# What is deprecatedKey in JIRA permission API and what is usage

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to understand JIRA permission API. While making call to their permission service i.e.

http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/mypermissions [GET]

```
/rest/api/2/mypermissions?projectKey&projectId&issueKey&issueId
```

I am getting below response for current loggedIn user:

[image]

It is returning 2 properties for various permission key/node:

1. havePermission
2. deprecatedKey

Can you say what is its implementation and how it works ?

After observing the response I found that
 `deprecatedKey` property is not for all permission nodes
there are multiple permissions with same `id` (i.e. permissionId) but different `deprecatedKey` parameter

Comment: Have you checked out [the documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/-getPermissions)? it's pretty decent. Or is it not clear enough for you? If yes what's not clear then?

Comment: Yes, I had gone through the documentation, but didn't found any information about it. And basically I am not clear about what is the usage of "deprecatedKey" property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding of [the documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/-getPermissions) the permission model changed with JIRA 6.4 and the old permission keys became obsolete. Yet they were kept in the API for [backward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) reasons (i.e. so that the legacy clients using the old API don't get broken when the API changes).

Quote:

> Prior to version 6.4 this service returned project permissions with keys corresponding to `com.atlassian.jira.security.Permissions.Permission` constants. Since 6.4 those keys are considered deprecated and this service returns system project permission keys corresponding to constants defined in `com.atlassian.jira.permission.ProjectPermissions`. Permissions with legacy keys are still also returned for backwards compatibility, they are marked with an attribute deprecatedKey=true. The attribute is missing for project permissions with the current keys.

What that means is that for example in JIRA prior to v6.4 there was a permission called `VIEW_WORKFLOW_READONLY`. Starting from 6.4 probably another permission was added that obsoletes this permission (although I don't know which in this concrete example). So now this permission either has a different key or was incorporated into anoter permission set. Being split into a few newly introduced permissions is also an option.

Deprecation means that this old permission key should not be used anymore when developing new client apps and that it will be removed in the future versions of the API.

Read more about deprecation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation).

The other attribute `havePermission` just means that the requestor is granted permission with the particular key in the given context (Project/Issue).